# Rails 4 progress bar while deleting remote file with Fog and waiting for controller respond_to

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, fog

I've seen plenty of Progress bar questions here but none of them help with what I am trying to do. Basically, I have a view and a controller in Rails 4 where the user can delete images associated with a record and then update the images div via jquery once the image has been deleted.

But the deletion is done remotely to a Google storage via Fog which takes a couple of seconds. I simply want to display a progress bar or spinner, or something while the image is being deleted and before the images div gets refreshed to let the users know that the page hasn't hung. I have everything working but the progress bar.

This is what I have:

```
#images_list
```

Is the div id that gets refreshed after deleting the image and contains all the images

The controller action:

```
def delete_image
  EntryImage.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js # js file that refreshes the images div
  end
end
```

.js file

```
$('#images_list').html("<%=j render 'entry/display_images' %>");
```

All very simple. But how can I load a spinner/progress bar while I am waiting for the controller to call the .js file?

`EntryImage.destroy` opens a Fog connection, does some renaming and deletes the image. Then when it returns the `.js` is called and the div is refreshed.

I'm sure this isn't something too hard, but I'm quite new to jquery, etc. Ideally I'd like to do this in a simple 'Railsy' way, using built-in technologies such as Coffeescript, jquery and even bootstrap (since I know it has a progress bar somewhere and we already use bootstrap in the project).

**Edit:**
I should also mention that the progress bar/spinner should be in a modal window in the center of the view to make sure the user sees it even if the page has scrolled because the entry has many images.

Thanks

**Edit2:**
Sorry for posting so much code but I can't figure out why the method suggested in the first answer won't work.
The delete buttons inside the `#images_list` won't trigger the hidden state for some reason, only the first one (outside the div) works:

```
<div id='images_toggle_div' style='display: none;'>
  <div class='well' style='overflow: auto;'>
    <a class="delete-btn" href="#">This one works!</a>
    <div class='hidden' id='spinner'>
      <img alt="Ajaxspinner" src="/assets/ajaxSpinner.gif" style="width: 200px;" />
    </div>

    <script>
      $('.delete-btn').click(function(){
        $('#spinner').toggleClass('hidden');
      });
    </script>

    <div id='images_list'>
      <div class='pull-left bordered'>
        <a href="http://rack.supersecret.com/526-3.jpg" target="_blank"><img alt="526 3" class="small_image" src="http://rack.supersecret.com/526-3.jpg?5090659" title="526-3.jpg (314 x 450)" /></a>
        <div class='tiny'>
          <a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=upc 9780767880268" target="_blank">9780767880268</a>
        </div>
        <a class="btn btn-mini btn-danger delete-btn" data-remote="true" href="#" title="Delete this image"><i class="icon-trash icon-white icon-large"></i> Delete</a>
      </div>
      <div class='pull-left bordered'>
        <a href="http://rack.supersecret.com/526-4.jpg" target="_blank"><img alt="526 4" class="small_image" src="http://rack.supersecret.com/526-4.jpg?5090659" title="526-4.jpg (391 x 500)" /></a>
        <div class='tiny'>
          <a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=upc 9780767880268" target="_blank">43396154162</a>
        </div>
        <a class="btn btn-mini btn-danger delete-btn" data-remote="true" href="#" title="Delete this image"><i class="icon-trash icon-white icon-large"></i> Delete</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a spinner thing, like for instance a gif or a font-awesome spinner-icon via jquery triggered by the click, and then in your js-response file, remove it when the images returns.

In your view:

```
%button#delete-btn Delete image

%img.hidden#spinner{src: "assets/spinner.gif"}
#images_list

:javascript
  $('#delete-btn').click(function(){
    $('#spinner').toggleClass('hidden');
  });
```

In your .js.erb

```
$('#spinner').toggleClass('hidden');
$('#images_list').html("<%=j render 'entry/display_images' %>");
```

This since you only get to the js.erb file once the images returns if I understand correctly. Otherwise I would prefer to have all the object specific DOM-manipulation done in the js.erb file.

CSS:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/b3rgstrom/wr2jz/1/

Comment: This sounds good, but the problem is there is nowhere for me to put the spinner on the page where it will always be visible. If the entry has many images the page will scroll and the spinner will be lost. I probably need a modal window to come up. Will update the question.

Comment: You could have the spinner in a wrapperclass thats overlapping the entire viewport in hidden state. Here is a fiddle anyways for the example: http://jsfiddle.net/b3rgstrom/wr2jz/

Comment: Thanks, your jsfiddle works great but for some reason it won't work on my actual Rails page. I can't figure out why. If I put the delete button outside the #images_list div it works, inside it, with the same class `.delete-btn` it won't. I'm stumped on this one. I'll copy the html to see if I'm missing something obvious

Comment: add doc-ready around like so: http://jsfiddle.net/b3rgstrom/wr2jz/7/ and you should be OK. you might consider placing the javascript at the end of the body for good measure.

Comment: Thank you, this is great. I also wanted to thank you for your awesome dedication to this question. And if I may trouble you with 1 more thing: when you click the delete button, a confirmation dialog comes up. I'd like to hide the spinner if the user clicks the cancel button on the confirmation window. Is this possible?

Comment: And yet another little niggle is that when I click anywhere outside the spinner modal window, the spinner window disappears. I was wondering if I could avoid that. Again, thanks a lot for everything.

Comment: New fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/b3rgstrom/wr2jz/8/ I put the confirm or cancel buttons in the modal, but I'm sure you'll get the idea.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a standard alert dialog box (created by Rails with `data: { confirm: 'message'}` so I can't create an ID for the standard cancel and Ok buttons. I also can't add an ID for the window, it adds `data-id` to `id: 'confirm-window`.